# Is there any method to reverse words with retaining position's case

Tags: java, string

I need a function which accepts a string as input and reverser words with retaining position's case.

**Example:**

Input: "HeLlo woRld BEn"

Output: "olLeh dlRow NEb"

Comment: Not a direct method but you can split and do it

Comment: can you help me with that?

Comment: Why doesn't "olLeh" start with a capital letter?

Comment: can you show the code you have tried ?

Comment: `Character` class has `isUpperCase`, `isLowerCase`,`toUpperCase`, `toLowerCase` methods that will be your best friends here.

Comment: @AndyTurner my friend, the goal is to reverse a string without changing the case is that specific position. hope you get what am trying to say!?

Comment: @KevinAnderson thank you my friend!!! I appreciate that>

Comment: @Deadpool i dont have any idea with it so i dint even start it buddy!!!

Comment: The "O" should be capital in "OlLeh". Your example is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverseWordsRetainingPositionCase("HeLlo woRld BEn"));
    }

    static String reverseWordsRetainingPositionCase(String str) {
        String[] words = str.split("\\s+");// Split the string on space(s)
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);// Create a StringBuilder instance with the content of str
        for (String word : words) {
            // Find the word in sb and replace it with its reverse
            sb.replace(sb.indexOf(word), sb.indexOf(word) + word.length(), reverseCharsRetainingPositionCase(word));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    static String reverseCharsRetainingPositionCase(String word) {
        StringBuilder reversedWord = new StringBuilder(word).reverse();// Reverse the word
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            // If the character at i in the word is in upper case, change the case of the
            // character at i in the reversed word to upper case. Process the reversed word
            // in the same way for lower case.
            if (Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(i))) {
                reversedWord.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(reversedWord.charAt(i)));
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(word.charAt(i))) {
                reversedWord.setCharAt(i, Character.toLowerCase(reversedWord.charAt(i)));
            }
        }
        return reversedWord.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
OlLeh dlRow NEb
```

I have put enough comments in the code to make it easier for understanding. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 2):

We split the original sentence into words and reverse them using StringBuilder@reverse. We then create a character array representing the original words and the reversed words. We then loop through all characters and make sure the case is correct by checking for upper and lower case.

```java
    String reverse(String sentence) {
        char[] characters = sentence.toCharArray();

        String reversed = Stream.of(sentence.split(" "))
                .map(word -> new StringBuilder(word).reverse())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        char[] reversedCharacters = reversed.toCharArray();

        for (int index = 0; index < reversedCharacters.length; index++) {
            char characterAtIndex = characters[index];

            char characterAtReversedIndex = reversedCharacters[index];

            if (Character.isUpperCase(characterAtIndex) && Character.isLowerCase(characterAtReversedIndex)) {
                reversedCharacters[index] = Character.toUpperCase(characterAtReversedIndex);
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(characterAtIndex) && Character.isUpperCase(characterAtReversedIndex)) {
                reversedCharacters[index] = Character.toLowerCase(characterAtReversedIndex);
            }
        }
        return new String(reversedCharacters);
    }
```